# Why Apache2 doesn't search index.php in folder?

Tags: php, debian, apache2, lampp, xfce

I have a little problem.

When I look to my localhost website, I have to write to address bar `localhost/index.php`.

If I write only `localhost`, I get Apache2 Default Page, but my configuration files are set good (I think).

**httpd.conf (/opt/lampp/etc)**

```
DocumentRoot "/home/xfce/Documents/www/"
<Directory "/home/xfce/Documents/www/">
```

So what is and where is my problem?

I am using Debian Stretch (xfce).

Comment: Try to see if this does anything: `DirectoryIndex index.php index.html`

Comment: @HoogleyBoogley I have .php in `DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var index.php index.php3 index.php4`.

Comment: Make sure that .php is first. Because this means that index.html will be loaded and not .php. So change that line to this:  `DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.html.var index.php3 index.php4`

Comment: @HoogleyBoogley Doesn't work. But if index.html doesn't exist, why would it load it?